# sharing memory between two applications

Tags: c#, c++, process, shared-memory

I have two different windows applications (two different people writing the code). One is Written in C++ and another one is in C#. I need some way how to share data in RAM between them. One must writes data and another one just reads the written data. What should I use to make it most effective and fast?
Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

You can use [Memory Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

[Here](https://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3828586/Using-Memory-Mapped-Files-in-NET-40.htm) is an article describing how to use them.

Comment: They are limited to logical address space. (Max of 2GB in my case, although my RAM is 16GB)

Comment: This is not an issue since you can map multiple files.

Comment: Just FYI, page at the 2nd link is missing/disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590.aspx) [Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927.aspx).

> A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients. All instances of a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server communication. The use of instances enables multiple pipe clients to use the same named pipe simultaneously.
>
> Any process can access named pipes, subject to security checks, making named pipes an easy form of communication between related or unrelated processes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Windows [File Mapping Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to share memory between processes.