# How read Memory from another application - Share Data

Tags: c#, memory, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5, windows

We can **read / write** data in **memory** like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        sw.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(myStr);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now i want to write data on Ram (Memory = Random Access Memory) and read those data from **Another Applicatio**n?
How can i do that and **Share** a string in memory?

**Important Note :** I don't want to write any data on hard disk.
**Edit :** My .net version is 3.5

Comment: Hmm, no, the process boundary is a very tall wall.  Look at the System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles namespace to get somewhere.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I am using .net 3.5

Comment: Well, stop using it.  Nobody has to be stuck on an 8 year old version of free software.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could write a service that acts as a delegate between the two processes. Without some sort of middle-man, it doesn't seem like you are going to be able to do what you want. Try giving more clarification in your question as to what you are actually trying to accomplish, and maybe someone can be more helpful.

Comment: For some reasons i can't install .net 4 on my server. what is the problem?

Comment: @MoonLight generally "read memory of other application" means something totally different compared to "share" (first usually mean `ReadPRocessMemory`, later imply active cooperation - Inter-Process-Communication). You could have improved your question by searching for either https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20read%20memory%20different%20process OR https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20ipc and adding information why top results did not work for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for .net **3.5** 
Memory mapped files have been in windows for a while, so even .net 3.5 don't have them, it is still possible to wrap native api. Github project [filemap](https://github.com/tomasr/filemap) does that. Unfortunately, they don't have example how to share memory mapped file between two processes.

---

This answer is useful for .NET Framework **4.6 and 4.5**
Not **3.5**

---

I don't think you can share a memory stream between two processes. Most close would be [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894224/sharing-memory-between-two-applications) for other options.

Comment: Pay attention on my .net version please.

Comment: Pay attention to your post, when you type it. You've posted version requirement after my answer as edit and also pinvoke available at your .net version.

Comment: no man, it was on my tags. there is no need to discuss about that. please edit your answer and help about my question.