# Share data between C# applications on same pc

Tags: c#

I'm creating my own gta V mod in c# which is a dll file, And I also have a other application that has a speedometer on it, the way I used to do it was create a file and let the form read it and the dll write it but it is way to unstable as it often throws the error that it cannot access the file :/ I also tried using pipes but that was too laggy as it was constantly throwing exceptions about it not existing...

Is there a way I can just let the dll send the speed to the application on the same pc and let the application read it and put it in a textbox(or in this case set the speedometer value)?

Thanks

Comment: Named pipes was probably a good choice but use a higher level wrapper around it to make it easier. [Like WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example).

Comment: How about memory mapped files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894224/sharing-memory-between-two-applications