# Sending text messages to external program c#

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, communication

I want to write smth. in to an external program by using a button click event in my WPF Application.
Is there a possibilty to do this? I found anything in the net yet...
It is an .exe to send commands to an arduino and it would be more simple to write directly into the (external) console than to import the .dll into my program. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Can't you simply send it through serial port?

Comment: Have you tried http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Csharp ?

Comment: Shared memory? [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894224/sharing-memory-between-two-applications)

Comment: Thank you, I went for sending it through serial port